# AngularJS cards carousel: return card to the end of array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using [this example](http://codepen.io/alexndreazevedo/pen/zGQMME) to create a card carousel. But I want to modify it so I can return every swiped card to the end of the set of cards. Meaning, endless swiping.
I tried using `splice()` at the `cardDestroyed` function like this but it did not work:

```
$scope.cardDestroyed = function(index) {
$scope.cards.splice($scope.cards[$scope.cards.length+1], 0, index);
 };
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var card = $scope.cards[index];
$scope.cards.splice(index, 1);
$scope.cards.push(card);
```

(I'm assuming `index` is the index in the Array that the card is located at)

Comment: the card is returned at the beginning of the array :/

Comment: @Hana Are you sure? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp `.push()` will simply put the item at the end of the Array.